# AMPscript - DataExtensionRowCount

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am having some trouble with the DataExtensionRowCount function. I am trying to SET a Data Extension name at the start so I do not need to update the AMPscript in multiple places every time I change the Data Extension.

I have got the below to work fine without setting the Data Extension. However, I get an error when I try to call @De1. Is this possible?

```
%%[ 
Var @TotalCount
SET @TotalCount = DataExtensionRowCount("TestDE")
]%%

                 %%=v(@TotalCount)=%% 


%%[ 
Var @TotalCount, @De1
SET @De1 = TestDE
SET @TotalCount = DataExtensionRowCount(@De1)
]%%

                 %%=v(@TotalCount)=%%
```

Comment: You need to put the value of `@De1` in quotes. E.g. `Set @De1 = "TestDE"` otherwise it will be viewed as a personalization string/attribute, which it is not and will cause it to fail

Comment: @Gortonington: Go ahead and create an answer for it, but include numbers in your answer, which can be set without quotes afaik. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the value of `@De1` in quotes. E.g. `Set @De1 = "TestDE"` otherwise it will be viewed as a personalization string/attribute, which it is not and will cause it to fail.

The exceptions are for numbers which do not need quotes. I am not positive but may also be  true with boolean `true` or `false`. I personally just use 1 and 0 for this, so not positive.